# Using IdentityServer3 with Ws-Federation plugin to become in-place ADFS server for local development

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, adfs, identityserver3

I have a project that will use ADFS as identity provider.

I thought about using IdentityServer3 with Ws-Federation addon to provide as a stand-in replacement for development.

As I share the repo among my team mates, they won't have to rely on a centralized identity provider.

When it goes production, we can detach IdentityServer3.

Is this doable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's doable but idsrv doesn't have claims rules etc.

So there is extra work to generate the correct claim set.

What's the issue with having a centralized identity provider.?